# Why Named Queries?

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, named-query

I'd like to know using named queries leads to better performance or not.
When and where will named queries be compiled and deployed?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for named queries is security: it enforces the use of query parameters (i.e., you will not be able to build your query with some string concatenation) and will avoid that a bug in your program will end up executing a malicious query.

Comment: Prevents SQL INJECTION? So we can implement our embedded queries with parameters? Is there another advetage?

Answer (score 0):

Named queries will be compilied at starting application server and destroying after stoping application server. So no performance problems at runtime

Comment: Will named queries be pooled on application start up?